# Internet socket connection stops the app on android

Tags: java, android, class, sockets

I have a problem with my app. I have a MainActivity, where is a drawer with fragments. From Scan fragment I call Scan Activity. This part is workng. And when I press back button, it goes back to MainActivity with ScanFragment. And there is also socket operation to send the code and maybe there is the problem. When I turn off wifi, it shows I/O error in Toast, but when I try to send the data, it goes into black screen. I found the problem in profiler, that MainActivity do not start after closing Scan activity, but the app is still running.

[image: Image of Missing Activity]

After a while android ask, if close non responding app. I tried to move all classes and functions into MainActivity, but then scanner wont start. Thanks for any help

My code of `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ScanFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_scan);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_scan:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ScanFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_okruh:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new OkruhFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_kzavozu:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new KZavozuFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_zprava:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ZpravaFragment()).commit();
                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Code of `ScanFragment.java`:

```
public class ScanFragment extends Fragment {
    String kod;
    String hostname = (address);
    int port = (number);

    Date date;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS");

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan, container, false);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                zapnoutSkener();
            }
        });
        Button rucne = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        final EditText rucneKod = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.numberInput);

        rucne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                odeslat(rucneKod.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public class Spojeni extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Log.i("hodnota", strings[0]);
            Log.i("kod", strings[1]);
            try (Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port)) {
                OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outputStream, true);
                writer.println(strings[0] + ";" + kod + ";" + simpleDateFormat.format(date));

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line = reader.readLine();
                socket.close();
                return line;
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                return "Server nebezi, zopakujte odeslani";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "I/O Error, zkontrolujte pripojeni k internetu";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "Obecny error";
            }
        }
    }

    public void zapnoutSkener() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ScanOkno.class);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Zapinani akce", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("Zapinani skeneru", "ted");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    public void odeslat(String kod) {
        date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Odesílám kód: " + kod, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Spojeni spojit = new Spojeni();
        String odpoved = null;
        try {
            odpoved = spojit.execute("SCAN", kod).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("Odpoved", odpoved);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Odpoved: " + odpoved, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            Log.i("KOD", String.valueOf(resultCode));
            if (resultCode == 1) {
                String result = data.getStringExtra("code");
                Log.i("Vysledek", result);
                odeslat(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code of scanner activity `ScanOkno.java`:

```
public class ScanOkno extends AppCompatActivity implements BarcodeReader.BarcodeReaderListener {

    private BarcodeReader barcodeReader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_okno);
        barcodeReader = (BarcodeReader) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.barcode_fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanned(Barcode barcode) {
        // play beep sound
        barcodeReader.playBeep();
        String kod = barcode.rawValue;
        barcodeReader.pauseScanning();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("code", barcode.rawValue);
        setResult(1, intent);
        finish();
        //Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScannedMultiple(List<Barcode> list) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapScanned(SparseArray<Barcode> sparseArray) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScanError(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraPermissionDenied() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera permission denied!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
odpoved = spojit.execute("SCAN", kod).get()
```

is your problem. Calling `get()` on an AsyncTask blocks the current Thread until the task completes, essentially defeating the purpose of an AsyncTask.

Consider using a callback.

First, make Spojeni a static class:

```
public static class Spojeni extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

This will prevent memory leaks from occurring. I do see some variables that you access inside the parent class, but you can pass them in your call to `execute()` and retrieve them from your AsyncTask there.

Then, create an interface (can be a child of ScanFragment or in its own file):

```
public interface OnTaskCompleteListener {
    void onTaskComplete(String result);
}
```

Add a constructor and a global variable to your AsyncTask:

```
private OnTaskCompleteListener listener;

public Spojeni(OnTaskCompleteListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

And implement `onPostExecute()`:

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute(String result) {
    listener.onTaskComplete(result);
}
```

When you create an instance of Spojeni:

```
new Spojeni(new OnTaskCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTaskComplete(String result) {
        //handle the result
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I need to send number `kod` and string `"SCAN"`. Where I can input these data?

Comment: You're already passing them in your `execute()` call and even logging them inside `doInBackground()`. Just assign `strings[0]` and `strings[1]` to variables instead of logging them.

Comment: So `odpoved = spojit.execute("SCAN",kod).get()` stays in code?

Comment: Remove the `get()` and handle the string result in the listener instead.

Comment: Okay, but now I have an error in line `Spojeni spojit = new Spojeni();` Error: `Spojeni (OnTaskCompleteListener) in Spojeni cannot be applied to ()`. I must to fill something into brackets in `Spojeni spojit = new Spojeni();`?

Comment: Look at the last thing I put in my answer.

Comment: This is now my code: https://codeshare.io/2Bn8An. I do not understand. I can't remove `Spojeni spojit = new Spojeni();`, because `spojit` will be missing there.

Comment: Oh, you mean, that I will replace `Spojeni spojit = new Spojeni();` and `spojit.execute("SCAN",kod)` with `Spojeni.execute(doInBackground("SCAN",kod);` ?

Comment: No. Remove `get()`. Look up how to pass arguments to an AsyncTask. You're already doing it, and I'm not sure how else to explain it.

Comment: I removed an .get(), but still getting an error :-(. [picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsywH.png). Should i create an another constructor with empty brackets?

Comment: You need to replace that statement with the one in my answer. You're not supposed to just randomly shove it in.

Comment: Oh, I have it. It is now working and it was very simple. Thank you for your patience.